# State update not showing the changes inside render, even though the state is updated

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am implementing multiple image upload and its preview. Here i m updating state , but not showing the changes inside the render. When value is updated to the state variable, i need to print hello , but its not priting

```
state={
    allImages:[]
}

handleChange=(e)=>{

   let image=[];
   for(let i of e.target.files){

       const reader=new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(i);

       reader.onload=()=>{
         if(reader.readyState===2){
             image.push(reader.result);
         }
       }
     }
   this.setState({allImages:image});
}

render(){
  return (
          {this.state.allImages.map(i=><h1>Hello<h1>)
   )
}
```

Comment: have you checked if you have any error on the console ?

Comment: no error...i have a console.log(state-Variable) inside the render to show the state variable value. So when ever the value changes, console should display the changed value. But the console never prints anything even after the state is updated.

Comment: I think this might be because your `setState` is called before the `onload` function finishes returning anything, so you're setting the state to an empty array

Comment: Yeh got it.... thnx.....Now i m setting the state inside the onload function and its working pretty well...